# keep font/text skewed when hover

Tags: html, css

I have made a CSS hover event, when you hover on the nav bar, the font fades black and goes italic like.

When I hover for longer than the 2s time it takes to transition, it goes back to normal.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header">
    <ul id="header-logo">
        <li id="nav"><a href="#" id="title">Josh Murray</a></li>
        <li id="nav-spacing"></li>
        <li id="nav"><a href="#" id="no-underline">Home</a></li>
        <li id="nav"><a href="#" id="no-underline">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li id="nav"><a href="#" id="no-underline">Purchase</a></li>
        <li id="nav"><a href="#" id="no-underline">About</a></li>
        <li id="nav"><a href="#" id="no-underline">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="bottom-header">
        <!-- Gradient goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#no-underline {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 2s linear;
    transition: all 2s linear;
}

#no-underline:hover {
    color: black;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    -o-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gaxy2qb/)

I would like the font to stay like its italic... I cannot figure it out

Thank you!

Comment: You're using the `id` attribute incorrectly. Use a `class` instead.

Comment: Add `display: inline-block;` to your rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `display: inline-block;` to your :hover effect. Also, you are using the same ID tag multiple times, which is wrong. You should be using `class="no-underline"` and `.no-underline, .no-underline:hover`

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/f9etuq32/1/

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, what you want is to change the font styling to italics when hovered over, and then when the mouse is removed, change the color back, but leave the italics. What I would do is this:

First of all, change the multiple occurences of the same ID to  a class instead. So instead of

```
<li id='nav'></li>
```

use this

```
<li class='nav'></li>
```

Secondly, I would use JQuery to do what you want with the text.

Begin JQuery:

```
//below makes the color black and the text italics when <li> hovered over
$(".nav").mouseenter(function(){
$(this).css('color', 'black');
$(this).css('font-style', 'italic');
});
```

then

```
//below makes the color back to normal, but leaves the italics when the 
//the mouse goes off the item
$(".nav").mouseleave(function(){
$(this).css('color', 'white');
});
```

my proof of concept is in [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7ze469o/)